# TensorBoard could not bind to port 6006, it was already in use

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorboard

I already closed the Tensorboard before, but after I open new terminal and re-run the command `tensorboard --logdir /tmp/retrain_logs`, it produces following error:

> E0128 12:24:08.469702 MainThread program.py:201] TensorBoard could not
>   bind to port 6006, it was already in use
>
> E0128 12:24:08.469702 140707008960320 program.py:201] TensorBoard
>   could not bind to port 6006, it was already in use
>
> ERROR: TensorBoard could not bind to port 6006, it was already in use

Anybody knows the how could this happen? I can easily restart the PC, but now I'm in the middle of training my dataset (unfortunately I haven't set checkpoint) so I don't want to terminate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes, the port continues to be occupied in spite of ending the instance.

In that case,

you can first check if your port is still occupied by:

```
lsof -i:6006
```

and then, using the PID listed above to kill the tcp instance:

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: I've been using a Colab that recently started popping this error; never had it before but now I get it every time. I've used this PID kill command before and it didn't solve the problem—each new runtime would encounter the same port issue. I thought ti might be a browser-related issue so I tried running on Safari, and also restarted and used a clean guest account on Chrome with no other windows open. No change.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why your 6006 port is in use, but you can just try to use another port:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/retrain_logs  --port=8008
```

Comment: I have no strong background in networking, I'm curious how do you choose port? Why 8008?

Comment: It has no special meaning (except being above 1024, which means it is not a privileged port which normal users cannot use to run servers).