# Running tensorboard and python script at the same time

Tags: python, tensorboard, slurm

I want to submit an sbatch script. The main part is training a deep learning model but I also want to run tensorboard at the same time for logging.

Now I have my script.slurm

```sh
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=6
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=5GB
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1

tensorboard --logdir:runs
python3 trainloop.py
```

It launches tensorboard and runs the script only after I close tensorboard server.
I changed it to

```sh
srun tensorboard --logdir:runs &
srun python3 trainloop.py
```

but now it loops for some reason trying to launch tensorboard multiple times and gives this error

```
E1114 21:45:51.826188 47451355829184 program.py:298] TensorBoard could not bind to port 8872, it was already in use
```

What is the best approach to have tensorboard server running alongside my script?

Comment: Could you please refer to the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395201/tensorboard-could-not-bind-to-port-6006-it-was-already-in-use)  and  also look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZU6YgT6e4BI) where the error addressed..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the ampersand (`&`) is the right solution, but you should not be using `srun` as srun will start as many tasks (i.e. as many instances of `tensorboard --logdir:runs` as there are tasks requested with `--ntasks-per-node=6`, which will produce the "already in use" error. Same for the second `srun`, it will start 6 instances of `python3 trainloop.py` unless that script uses [MPI](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) behind the scenes.

So this

```
tensorboard --logdir:runs &
python3 trainloop.py
```

should do what you want.

Comment: If I have multithreading in my python script (PyTorch Dataloader `num_workers`) will this method make use of the 6 tasks I am allocating in my slurm script?

Comment: Normally yes, you should be able to easily verify it